# how to insert new row on the bottom of jtable rows

Tags: java, swing

I have i jTable which increases automatically as data are added from MYSQL, i want to show total of marks on the bottom of other rows, it means that if table gets results of five rows it must append automatically a sixth row which contains text Total and its result in number. my problem is that all results are coming vertically in column i am anable to append a Total results on the bottom of the table. please help me :

My code :

```
          try {
        String sql = "SELECT Module_Title as 'Module Title', Assignment_One as 'Ass 1',Assignment_Two as 'Ass 2', Cat_One as 'Cat 1',Cat_Two as 'Cat 2',Course_Work as 'CW', Final_Exam as 'FE', SUM(Total) as 'Total marks' FROM ace_result_register arr WHERE arr.Registration_No= '" + this.Rsltsrch_txtfld.getText() + "'";
        this.pst = this.conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        this.rs = this.pst.executeQuery();
        if (this.rstl_tbl2.getRowCount() >= 0 && this.rstl_tbl2.getRowCount() < 1000) {
            this.rstl_tbl2.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel((ResultSet)this.rs));
            this.rstl_tbl2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.GRAY, 1));
            this.rstl_tbl2.getTableHeader().setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.GRAY, 1));
            this.jScrollPane3.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
            this.jScrollPane3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(900, 18 + this.rstl_tbl2.getRowCount() * this.rstl_tbl2.getRowHeight()));
            DefaultTableCellRenderer centerRenderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
            centerRenderer.setHorizontalAlignment(0);
            this.rstl_tbl2.getColumn("Module Title").setCellRenderer(centerRenderer);
            this.rstl_tbl2.getColumn("Ass 1").setCellRenderer(centerRenderer);
            this.rstl_tbl2.getColumn("Ass 2").setCellRenderer(centerRenderer);
            this.rstl_tbl2.getColumn("Cat 1").setCellRenderer(centerRenderer);
            this.rstl_tbl2.getColumn("Cat 2").setCellRenderer(centerRenderer);
            this.rstl_tbl2.getColumn("CW").setCellRenderer(centerRenderer);
            this.rstl_tbl2.getColumn("FE").setCellRenderer(centerRenderer);
            this.rstl_tbl2.getColumn("Total").setCellRenderer(centerRenderer);
            this.rstl_tbl2.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(new TextAreaCellRenderer());

        }
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
```

Comment: [For example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17585112/calculate-the-subtotal-while-every-time-adding-a-new-row-in-jtable/17585465#17585465) and [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43334278/setting-a-listener-to-a-tablemodel-to-update-as-required/43334813#43334813)

Comment: You could define your own `TableModel` which has a "protected" row (the last one) whose value you store in the `TableModel`, as rows are added and removed you update the value (and trigger the appropriate model event)

Comment: @MadProgrammer, thank you for your advice , but i don't see the way i can do it please help me with this code of mine

Comment: Start by getting rid of `DbUtils` and relying on your own custom `TableModel`

Comment: @MadProgrammer  thnx, please provide me a link of how to use `DbUtils`