# How do I optimize event processing in Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, listener

My program uses a spreadsheet like JTable with thousands of rows. If the user changes one cell value, event listeners execute some expensive listener functions. Each execution takes less than a second.

But operations like "replace all" in a column cause a long delay, because the event listeners execute once for each changed rows.

How can I optimize the execution of the listeners?

(I think, all table listener events should be somehow deactivated during operations like "replace all" and should be executed once at the end. Ideally I do not want to adapt each listener separately.)

The following code shows the problem. With the button "Fill Table" a function fills each cell except the last one with a number. The table listener executes a sum operation for each cell change. Because this calculation is fast, I inserted a Thread.sleep function to simulate an expensive operation. The program hangs some seconds after pressing "Fill Table".

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelEvent;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelListener;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;

public class TableListenerExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TableListenerExample().startGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    public void startGUI() {
        JFrame tableFrame = new JFrame();
        tableFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        tableFrame.setTitle("Table Example");
        tableFrame.setSize(700, 860);
        tableFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        Object[][] data = new Object[100][1];
        String[] columnNames = {"Column 1"};
        JTable exampleJTable = new JTable(data, columnNames);
        JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(exampleJTable);
        TableModel tabModel = exampleJTable.getModel();

        // the example uses only one table model listener event
        tabModel.addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener() {
            @Override
            public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
                if (e.getFirstRow() == e.getLastRow() && e.getLastRow() == tabModel.getRowCount() - 1) {
                    // ignore changes in the sum cell
                    return;
                }
                TableModel tabModel = exampleJTable.getModel();
                Object cellValue;
                Integer cellValueI;
                Integer total = 0;
                // calculate a sum of all cells
                for (int i = 0; i < tabModel.getRowCount() - 1; i++) {
                    cellValue = tabModel.getValueAt(i, 0);
                    cellValueI = 0;
                    try {
                        cellValueI = Integer.parseInt((String) cellValue);
                    } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                        //ignore
                    }
                    total += cellValueI;
                }
                try {
                    // simulate the time delay for a bigger calculation
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    // ignore
                }
                // write the sum in the last cell
                tabModel.setValueAt("Sum: " + total, tabModel.getRowCount() - 1, 0);
            }
        });

        tableFrame.add(sp, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JButton fillButton = new JButton("Fill Table");
        tableFrame.add(fillButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        fillButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                TableModel tabModel = exampleJTable.getModel();
                for (int i = 0; i < tabModel.getRowCount() - 1; i++) {
                    tabModel.setValueAt(Integer.toString(i + 1), i, 0);
                }
            }
        });
        tableFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: `all table listener events should be somehow deactivated during operations like ` 1) remove the listener 2) do the long running task 3) add the listener back to the table.

Comment: Perform the operations on a new `TableModel`, swap the models. When I was doing row/column tallying, I would tend to keep a "running" tally, I would then only use the cell which had changed to update this "running" tally, rather then recalculating the all the values

Comment: Shouldn't this question is be asked on code review?

Comment: For [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43334278/setting-a-listener-to-a-tablemodel-to-update-as-required/43334813#43334813) and [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17585112/calculate-the-subtotal-while-every-time-adding-a-new-row-in-jtable/17585465#17585465)